# SAS Programming: Assignging an array to a dataset column

Tags: arrays, sas

I have data set and I would like to assign an array to one of my columns.

As an example:

```
            x     y    z
            2     1    5
            9     3    5
            2     3    4
```

I would like to assign an array Arrayx to variable x so that Arrayx{1}=2,Arrayx{2}=9 and Arrayx{3}=2.

Is this possible in SAS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. The SAS Data Step operates as an outerloop around the data set.  You have access to the current record and lagged values through the lagX() functions.  Arrays operated across rows, not columns.

This requires you to rethink how you solve your problem.  If you need help with that, post a question and I am sure someone here will give you a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
data arrayout ;
  set mydata (obs=3) ;
  array arrayx{3} ;
  retain arrayx . ;

  n+1 ;
  arrayx{n} = x ;

  keep arrayx: ;
run ;
```

What if there's 10 observations? Do you want an array 10 elements 'wide'? You might be better looking at PROC TRANSPOSE.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for would be a column vector in SAS/IML, if you can use that (SAS/IML is similar to R in that it works with matrices as its primary data object, not rowwise datasets).  In base SAS, you can't do it without restructuring the data (like Chris shows).